# Navigating to custom component from standard opportunity details page in salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In salesforce1 opportunity detail page I have a custom link url button in that I have given the url of the component. But when I click the button its saying'you can't view this Page either you don't have permission or the page is not supported in mobile devices'.

But when i click that from salesforce org detail page its opening.

Is there a  way to navigate to custom lightning component from standard detail view in salesforce1 and to pass the current record id to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't have that ability yet. Safe harbor: the recordTab interface is currently in pilot with some orgs to provide that feature.